# finding Login screen continue-booting-to-desktop-in-background utility

Tags: windows-7

I got a new laptop and can't figure out one of the tweaks I installed on my old laptop... to copy it to the new one.

What it is: Windows 7 would start up to the Login screen, but would continue booting to the desktop (in the background), essentially turning the Login screen into a Lockscreen.

Since there seems to be no icon for it (or I can't find it at the moment)... I don't remember what it's called or where it's loaded, how to find/download it again, etc. I've tried googling a couple times...

It was just nice to start the computer, walk away... then come back and log in...right to a fully loaded desktop...without waiting for everything to load up.

Anyone know which 'utility' does this?? Or... how to isolate what software is running (on old laptop) that allows this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

nice idea. The way I see it, you can duplicate the functionality by setting the Windows 7 to automatically logon, then set it to automatically lock upon logging in.

In start menu, type `netplwiz`, then run it. Clear the check box on `"Users must enter ..."`, when you click Apply, enter your password on the dialog box.
Now, on Explorer, open `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` create a new Shortcut there, on Target, enter `rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation`

Of course, the security risk would be if someone disable or delete the shortcut you just created (easy if they access your computer when logged in or they have administrator access), or just simply disable it while it just logged in before the lock command executed, then your computer is now wide open for anyone without password.