# Run interactive task even if user is not logged on Windows

Tags: windows, user-accounts, windows-task-scheduler, automatic-logon, interactive

I have an application which automates my everyday task of logging into some website and doing repetetive actions. This app starts as a scheduled task everyday at 7.30am.

The problem arises when I have my machine restarted (rebooted) but forgot to log into my windows user account (it is password protected). So windows sits at logon screen and scheduled app won't start.

I'm awaer of these possible ways to solve it, but aren't complete to my needs:

1) I know of 'Run if user is not logged in' option in Task Scheduler. It will not help as I want it run in interactive mode.
2) I know of possible solution to enable Autologin for my user account by setting my login/pass in Registry. That would make it possible for everyone to access my computer.

So my question is: Is there any possible way of booting my windows user account Automatically, but keep screen locked? That way I keep all my wishes in place. My scheduled app will start properly and noone can access my computer until they log in.

I'm sure many people have stumpled on this issue. Please share your solutions guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7: Automatically login and lock](http://superuser.com/questions/352616/windows-7-automatically-login-and-lock), [Log in Windows 8 account automatically, keeping it locked](http://superuser.com/questions/518307/log-in-windows-8-account-automatically-keeping-it-locked), [finding Login screen continue-booting-to-desktop-in-background utility](http://superuser.com/questions/437724/finding-login-screen), [Launch AutoStart programs before login](http://superuser.com/questions/267882), [How to lock Windows screen on startup?](http://superuser.com/questions/614477) ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [Autologon from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx) to autologon, but add a scheduled task with a trigger (start at login) and enter this command in the task scheduler

Program: **rundll32.exe** and as parameters: **user32.dll,LockWorkStation**

and create the task. The rundll32 command locks the PC after the automatic logon. So you get your task running but the PC will be locked.

Comment: I didn't know about built-in windows feature to lock screen. And using it on logon is a great idea. Thank you!