# Task Scheduler doesn't start my exe for the next day

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

I have an application made in Visual Studio 2013 and I use Task Scheduler to run .exe version. Task is set to work every day whether user is logged on or not. Created Task Scheduler will work on the day when is created but when I turn off PC and tomorrow turn on PC in Task Scheduler for my task there is nothing in 'Next Run Time' and task doesn't running my application. If I open task and just confirmed OK it will start again to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this topic : [Run interactive task even if user is not logged on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/616206/run-interactive-task-even-if-user-is-not-logged-on-windows)

This methods automatically logs in, runs the task, and locks the machine right after.

Else, if you are simply looking to run the application on boot after logging on, why not place it in Window's startup folder?

```
C:\Users\YOUR-USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Start-up
```

Create a shortcut of your exe and drop it in the above directory - the .exe will run once Window boots up.

Comment: I have a task that need to run during all day. This option with WIndow's startup folder will run the exe only once on start up?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the task? Yes, the startup folder will only run the program once on start, but it should not exit the task unless expilicitly killed or closed.

Comment: Task scheduler is excellent option for this but PC has to be always turn on whether user is logged on or not. So for now I think I will use Task scheduler.